# Word or phrase to describe a couple that is perfect?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a good word or phrase for a couple that is perfect?

Would that be referred to as a good match, or is there a better choice?

Also, is there a word or phrase to describe that when the girlfriend and boyfriend just are very similar in appearance?

Comment: A couple that seems to be just perfect is called "a perfect couple".  Seriously.

Comment: In a dialectic twist, the phrase for a perfect couple is "couple terror".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be [made for each other](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/made+for+each+other):

> - [of two people] very well suited romantically. Bill and Jane were made for each other. Mr. and Mrs. Smith were not exactly made for each other. They really don't get along.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms)

Answer (score 4):

> A match made in heaven.

This is a pretty common expression.

Answer (score 2):

*perfect for each other*

[Good Will Hunting (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/quotes)

> Sean: You're not perfect, sport, and let me save you the suspense:
>   this girl you've met, she's not perfect either. But the question is
>   whether or not you're perfect for each other.

[image]

Comment: You have a 10 Billion Karma on Reddit, don't you? +1 for Williams.

Answer (score 1):

There have been other ways to interpret this term, but ***soul mates*** is occasionally used to refer to a "perfect" couple.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply - a **Perfect pair/couple/duo/etc............**